# Removing tags w/ prefix using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to access tags with prefix using HAP but the following do not work (they return nothing):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[name() ='sc:xslfile']");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*['sc:xslfile']");
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

HTML looks like this:

`<p>Men's Standings<br />
<sc:xslfile runat="server" datasource="/Global/Tables/1_01/9859_" id="WC_9859"></sc:xslfile>
<br /><br /><br />
Women's Standings
<br /><sc:xslfile runat="server" datasource="/Global/Tables/1_01/9860_" id="WC_9860"></sc:xslfile></p>`

@Pat, I tried starts-with but still no go.

Maybe because the tags are empty?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your HTML document?

Comment: The posted html does not come through

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You may be able to use the starts-with selector.</strike>

i.e:

```
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[starts-with(@class, 'cnn_')]");
```

Where @class is the attribute you are looking for.

Update:

If you're interested in just the datasource and/or id you could run:

```
//*[@datasource]
```

or

```
//*[contains(@id, 'WC_']
```

However knowing what you're trying to extract would help refine the selector.